# How to disable the Binance Spot API PRICE_FILTER?

Tags: python, binance, binance-api-client

I am working on the Binance SPOT API with Python. Regarding the Symbol/Price filters for assets it says in the documentation [here](https://github.com/binance/binance-spot-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md#price_filter):

> The PRICE_FILTER defines the price rules for a symbol. There are 3 parts:

> minPrice defines the minimum price/stopPrice allowed; disabled on minPrice == 0.
> maxPrice defines the maximum price/stopPrice allowed; disabled on maxPrice == 0.
> tickSize defines the intervals that a price/stop...; disabled on tickSize == 0.

> **Any of the above variables can be set to 0**, which disables that rule in the price filter.

I have found no information about how to set those filters to '0' for disabling. Is there anyone that knows how to do this?

Best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think they mean they can be 0 in the api response but you cant set this yourself as you are just the consumer of their api. So if they are not 0 you have to follow these rules to ensure you dont get an error.

https://github.com/binance/binance-spot-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md#filters

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.